# Unable to open more than five Chrome browers with Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I launch the hub and node:

```
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node 
    -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register 
    -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=6,platform=WINDOWS 
    -timeout 0
    -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\...\chromedriver.exe
```

Then, I create Chrome driver instances:

```
    Dim desiredCapabilities As Remote.DesiredCapabilities = Remote.DesiredCapabilities.Chrome()
    Dim size As String = "--window-size={0},{1}"
    size = String.Format(size, browserWidth, browserHeight)
    Dim position As String = "--window-position={0},{1}"
    position = String.Format(position, browserWidth * index, 0)
    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", {size, position})
    driver = New Remote.RemoteWebDriver(New System.Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities)
```

Five works fine. The sixth times out waiting for Selenium to respond. Here is the error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session. Aborting test execution.
```

There is no activity in the node, so it appears the hub is not allocating the sixth request to the node. Is there a setting other than `maxInstances=6` that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running seperate nodes on different ports for each five browsers, and it worked:

Hub:

```
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub
```

First five:

```
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node -port 5555
    -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register 
    -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS 
    -timeout 0
    -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\...\chromedriver.exe
```

Next five:

```
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node -port 5556
    -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register 
    -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS 
    -timeout 0
    -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\...\chromedriver.exe
```